# Why is my cookie not secure?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, cookies

I'm trying to practice working with cookies and I'm trying to secure the cookie using my web config file. Which looks like the following-

```
<httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" requireSSL="false"/>
```

I have the following code for my CS. I was assuming if I set httpOnlyCookies to true that it will secure my cookie (again, I have minimum understanding of this concept so I apologize if this is a basic question).

CS Code-

```
 protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("UserInfo");

        cookie["username"] = txtEmail.Text;
        cookie["password"] = txtPassword.Text;

        if (txtEmail.Text != "" && txtPassword.Text != "")
        {
            Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
        }



        Response.Redirect("WebForm2.aspx");

    }
```

This is supposed to create the cookie. I used Chrome's cookie inspector to check if it is secure but it only secures when I set cookie.Secure to true. Is there a way I can secure this using my config file?

Many Thanks!

Comment: **never ever** store the users password in a cookie!

Comment: requireSSL="false" is the same as Secure.  so, you need to set requireSSL="true"  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcookie.secure(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: You can store a user token in a cookie but not passwords

Comment: Thank you so much everyone for your responses. I really appreciate it. Is there a different way to create a cookie that can default to secure using the same web.config settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First and foremost, You should ***NEVER*** store user credential in cookies. In `httpCookies` element `httpOnlyCookies` sets the `HttpOnly` flag in request header. `requireSSL` property make sure that the cookies are secure while transporting. So, you can set the `requireSSL="true"`

```
<httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" requireSSL="true"/>
```

See a nice post [Here](http://blog.codinghorror.com/protecting-your-cookies-httponly/)

Comment: Thanks for that Rahul! I'll make sure not to do that. I only made this as a simple test application to get a hang of cookies. I was wondering why "Secure" wasn't being marked as secure when I redirected myself after clicking the button. I thought setting httpOnlyCookies would suffice.

Answer (score 1):

The most glaring reason why it's insecure no matter what anyone says: because **you're storing the user's `password` in the cookie**. Don't *ever* do that!